# I have .htaccess but unable to write it web.config to deployee on IIS

Tags: php, iis

```
Satisfy any
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have deployed my website on godady but its url are not working there. Any one can help?
Note: I have tested this website on Apache server, is working fine, but on godady the server is IIS!

Comment: I have seen many answers on stackoverflow, but unable to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my issue by following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"  />                      
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```